# PowerShell: convertfrom-securestring -securekey

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use convertfrom-securestring with the parameter -securekey.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-7.2

1. Create ByteArray

```
 $length = 256
 $byte = $length / 8
 $key = New-Object Byte[] $byte
 $null = [Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create().GetBytes($key)
```

2. Convert ByteArray to String and convert String to SecureString

```
$keyString = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($key)
$secureKeyString = convertto-securestring $keyString -asPlainText -force
```

3. Finally use secureString as secureKey

```
convertfrom-securestring (convertto-securestring "stringToProtect" -asplaintext -force) -secureKey $secureKeyString
```

Exception: the specified key is not valid. Valid key length settings are either 128 bits, 192 bits, or 256 bits.

I tried several other ways to convert the byte array to string, e.g.:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($Key)
```

But in the end I always get the same exception. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[System.BitConverter]::ToString($key)` creates *human-readable* representation of the byte array stored in `$key` - which is *not* what you want - you want a string whose encoded representation is bit-for-bit the same as the key.

So instead, convert the `$key` array to a string with `UnicodeEncoding.GetString()` and use that to construct the `[securestring]` representation:

```
$secureKey = [securestring]::new()
foreach($char in [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($key).ToCharArray()){
    $secureKey.AppendChar($char)
}
```

`$secureKey` now points to an internal string that's *exactly* 32 bytes - or 256 bits - wide, usable as a key:

```
ConvertFrom-SecureString ("plainText" |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) -SecureKey $secureKey
```